# How to extract date from a string within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used pandas to read a table and created a dataframe named df. And one of the column within this dataframe named 'description' contains texts and numbers like below:

| description |
| --- |
| A CAKE 01/02/1989 |
| information 22031970 |
| some text |
| values 12345678987 |

I want to extract date from this field, and all dates within the fields are either in format 'dd/mm/yyyy' or 'ddmmyyyy', and output the result as:

[image]

I've tried `df['extracted_col'] = df['description'].str.replace('\D+', '')` but it gives me below so won't work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic approach is to *hardcode* the patterns and [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) each format of date separately :

```
df["dd/mm/yyyy"] = df["description"].str.extract(r"(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})", expand=False)

df["ddmmyyyy"] = df["description"].str.extract(r"\b(\d{8})\b", expand=False)
```

Just in case, we need to make sure to [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) the fake `ddmmyyyy` dates :

```
fake_dates = pd.to_datetime(df["ddmmyyyy"], format="%d%m%Y", errors="coerce").isna()

df["ddmmyyyy"] = df["ddmmyyyy"].mask(fake_dates)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

            description  dd/mm/yyyy  ddmmyyyy
0     A CAKE 01/02/1989  01/02/1989       NaN
1  information 22031970         NaN  22031970
2    some text 99889900         NaN       NaN
3    values 12345678987         NaN       NaN
```